# Return Identity Value From Table After Inserting Row

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, identity

I am trying to store the value of an identity value from table after inserting it into a row.

I want to store the value in currentID so I can store the value in another table which could be added more than once.

Any help or advice would be great!

```
    Dim currentID As Integer

        Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table (Databasevalue) VALUES ('" + formvalue + "');"                 

        cmd.Connection = sqlconninsertDB  

        sqlconninsertDB.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        **currentID = [get and store value]**

        sqlconninsertDB.Close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try adding this SELECT to your command:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table (Databasevalue) VALUES ('" + formvalue + "'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
```

And execute query like this:

```
Dim currentID as Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Instead of `.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Side note: Try not to use string concatenations when constructing inline-commands. Rather look into parametrized queries.

Answer (score 2):

With Sql Server you could pass two sql commands separating them with a semicolon.
The second command is a [SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) and this returns the last ID inserted in this scope.
You could execute both commands and retrieve the result with [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Please, take note to use a parameterized query instead of a string concatenation to avoid Sql Injection attacks and parsing problems.

```
    Dim currentID As Integer
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table (Databasevalue) VALUES (@formval); " + 
                      "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"                
    cmd.Connection = sqlconninsertDB  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@formval", formValue)
    sqlconninsertDB.Open()
    currentid = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    sqlconninsertDB.Close()
```

Comment: You can also use: Select [@@IDENTITY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)

Comment: @codechurn not really the same thing [SCOPE_IDENTITY vs @@IDENTITY vs IDENT_CURRENT](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103610/Difference-between-IDENTITY-SCOPE_IDENTITY-IDENT_C)